ASP.NET Core 8.0 Razor Pages and Progressive Web-App (Add to home screen on mobile) does not work properly (with ASP.NET Identity; Antiforgery)
I have an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Webpage which can be browsed to on smartphones (Android and IPhones).
I use ASP.NET Core Identity to secure access to the site.
My users want to add icons to the homescreens of their phones in order to access the site quickly (using the "add icon to homescreen"-feature of mobile versions of webbrowsers, which apparently "installs" a progressive web application, if its configured with a manifest).
I can't get this to work properly.
When accessing the site using the homescreen-button, the browser does not seem to load the local website data, especially not the cookies.
Missing the ASP.NET Identity Cookies, the server redirects to the login page.
If I enter credentials and post the form, the server responds with 400 Bad Request.
Excerpt from Logfile:
2024-12-10 15:00:42.8269|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter|Antiforgery token validation failed. The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateTokens(HttpContext httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)

The rejection of the antiforgery-token happens only in the context described above, nowhere else.
I have this problem for a long time now. Things I tried to resolve the issue:

Added a signed TLS-certificate to the IIS server (because I suspected the browser would not use local website data for websites, it doesn't trust).
Added a manifest.json to configure Progressive Web Application installation.
Added and used WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA.

Nothing of the above helped me with the issue.
The manifest:
{
  "short_name": "short name",
  "name": "name",
  "start_url": "/",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "browser",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "dir": "ltr",
  "lang": "de-DE",
  "theme_color": "#6FC2FF",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icons/rageguy512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/rageguy192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "purpose": "any"
    }
  ]
}

Reference in my _Layout.cshtml:
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

Program.cs
using WebEssentials.AspNetCore.Pwa;
// ...
builder.Services.AddProgressiveWebApp(new PwaOptions()
{
     Strategy = ServiceWorkerStrategy.Minimal,
});
// ...

Controller (LoginAsync()), which throws the 400 mentioned above:
using ***.Model.Identity;
using ***.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;



namespace ***.Areas.Identity.Controllers
{
    [Route("[Controller]/[Action]")]
    [Area("Identity")]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        private readonly IUserStore<ApplicationUser> _userStore;

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        private readonly ReturnUrlService _returnUrlService;



        public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
                                 IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore,
                                 UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                                 ReturnUrlService returnUrlService)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _returnUrlService = returnUrlService;
        }



        [TempData]
        public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }



        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromForm] LoginInputModel Input)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser? user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(Input.Id!);

                if (user == null)
                    return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password!, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return LocalRedirect(_returnUrlService.UrlUnescaped());
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("/Account/Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData.Set("ErrorMessage", "Login-Versuch ungültig!");
                    return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");
                }
            }

            TempData.Set("ErrorMessage", "Fehler!");
            return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");
        }



        public class LoginInputModel
        {
            [Required, StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Maximal 200 Zeichen.")]
            [Display(Name = "Benutzer")]
            public string? Id { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Es muss ein Passwort angegeben werden.")]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Passwort")]
            public string? Password { get; set; }
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "TimeRecordingPolicy")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutAsync()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");
        }
    }
}

Any help appreciated.
ADDENDUM:
To clarify: the problem is twofold:

The PWA does not seem to persist the Identity-cookie when it is closed. So, if the user closes the window and reopens it, the authenticated session is lost.
User cannot login, because login-request is denied because of rejected antiforgery-token.


sounds like it's authenticating a user before it's checking anti-forgery.  So when hitting the login page (that takes name/password) it'll start an anonymous session.  When posting, though, it's authenticating and then starting a new session (to avoid session fixation attack)... then it's checking anti-forgery which was set for the old anonymous one. Flipping that order should fix without having to set cookie(s) to lax. (anti-forgery token should be set to strict)

Oddly enough, the app.UseAntiforgery() statement is missing in my program.cs bootstrapping. The feature still seems to work. I checked with the browser's developer console, the antiforgery-cookie still is "strict". Just the Identity-cookie is "lax". I'm going to try it out with UseAntiforgery. I would feel better, if I could reset the Identity-cookie to "strict"

So I tested it: Identity-cookie persistence only if I set samesite=lax. Also: login only possible if I place Antiforgery middleware after Authentication and Authorization

I think RazorPages will automatically include UseAntiforgery.  samesite=lax for identity should be fine (that'd just allow the cookie to be sent when clicking a link from another site to yours... such as google search results.)  It's the anti-forgery that you really want to be strict.  (just feels more secure... not sure it has a big impact on security but can't hurt)

If you have middleware in program.cs that calls antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens,  (that's generally used if you need to pass an anti-forgery token to a front-end Single-Page-Application) then it'd set a new anti-forgery cookie if there is no cookie associated with the request.  When navigating by entering the URL, or probably from link in desktop, the origin is null.  So strict would probably not send any identity cookie.... when authorization/authentication runs, I guess you'd still get back anonymous and login form appears.  (be sure login form GET runs middleware if used)

It's a little confusing because you mention Razor pages being used here, but then the program.cs you show is for some kind of PWA?  I've never used "builder.Services.AddProgressiveWebApp", so not sure if it's a single-page where pages are created in front-end.  (Razor Pages would not be and anti-forgery tokens would be included in the forms as hidden fields.)

My application is razor pages, with Javascript doing AJAX calls sprinkled on here and there (if it's POST, I just copy name and value of a hidden input field which contains the antiforgery token and include it in the request body).
I added and configured a C# PWA-library from NuGet just to see what happens. A shot in the dark, so to speak. It's already removed.
The reason I mentioned PWA is, because from what I read, adding a homescreen button isn't just "open the browser and browse to this link", but a PWA. Which got me thinking I needed to support this in my code.

I still have the manifest.json, because some browsers would display our company's colors, which is kinda nice :).
"[...] antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens": no, i don't have that. Just standard antiforgery as provided by the razor pages framework.
The antiforgery-token is "strict", identity is "lax".
Thanks for your help!

I found the issue:
Apparently, cookies with samesite-attribute set to strict aren't handled very well in the context of progressive web applications. I configured the ASP.NET Identity Cookies to have samesite=lax, and problems disappeared.
Program.cs exerpt:
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    o.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
    o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    o.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(6);
    o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax; // <=====

    o.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(6);
    o.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

